# how much for Sound (ADC) reading in 24khz?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

how much "sound inputs" of high fidelify (128K 44kH) may be made via ordinary FPGA (Xilinx Spartan 3, what-so-ever) without using external ADC converters (only voltage-balanced input optically taken from audio jack)?

Here, [Generating a pure sine wave as output form FPGA using VHDL code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165266/generating-a-pure-sine-wave-as-output-form-fpga-using-vhdl-code/3184327#3184327) , it is pointed that FPGA may not perform such a job itself.

However, there are still 4 inputs/4 outputs of this resolution in the proposed test project, and...

what is a possibilty/amount of gates required to implement pre-DAC/pre-ADC output?

Comment: It depends on how much processing you want to do on the samples once you have them.

Comment: How many gates do your high fidelity sound input blocks take up?

Comment: got a sample, put it to DDR at certain address. Processing isn't the current question, just looking for the corrent way to do I/O.

Comment: Nathon, that's what is wanted to estimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't take analog signals.  All Xilinx FPGAs are fundamentally digital.  You need the ADC.